# Mechanize suddenly can't login anymore

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I have been trying to login to my airbnb account to scrape all my reservations. I was able to login and get the status of the reservation to appear with the following code but all of a sudden, it seems like I have been blocked out of Airbnb. The script would usually return all of the reservations' status nicely lined up and after calling the script for about 6 hours straight trying to figure out how to get this to work I suddenly couldn't get it to return the /my_reservations page anymore.

When I called

```
puts page.body
```

it kept returning the /log_in page

I can still access my account manually through the browser though. Does anyone know anything about this? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

agent = Mechanize.new {|a| a.user_agent_alias = "Mac Firefox"} page = agent.get('http://www.airbnb.com/my_reservations')

form = agent.page.form_with(action: "/authenticate") form.field_with(name: "email").value = "my_email@provider.com" form.field_with(name: "password").value = "my_password" form.submit

puts page.search('.label').text
```

Comment: It's very possible you were banned. It's not difficult to sense whether a request is coming from a browser or a script, either by sniffing the signature, or by watching the activity as the requests come in. I'd suggest reading their terms of service, and maybe even contact their tech-support to find out how they'd like you to access the data. Also, http://all-about-airbnb.com/post/127856658166/airbnb-public-api-coming-soon might help.

Comment: Thank you so much Tin Man! I really appreciate your answer! I will be more careful next time around to make sure I don't get booted.

Comment: Research "robots.txt", write your code to honor that, and to be a lightweight, very courteous, network citizen. It's all well documented "out there" and is the best way to accepted by a site. Remember, code can be vicious to a server and network when running at full speed and issuing requests as fast as it can process them. Don't be that guy.

Comment: Thank you Tin Man. I understand what you mean. I will write my code as to issue a request once, download the page source and then try scraping locally rather than issuing a request every time I am testing my code. Thank you for taking the time to offer advice. I really appreciate it.